# Aspectj pointcut expression

Tags: java, expression, aspectj, pointcut

I am having trouble with building aspectJ expression. I would like to run my advice when any of "QueryUtil" method is invoked from class "Report".

For example: if we invoke QueryUtil.*() inside of Report.*() -> Advice is executed.
If we invoke QueryUtil.*() from AnyOtherClass.* -> Advice is not executed.

I was thinking of cflow expression but still did not find a way to write it. I was thinking of something like this:

```
<pointcut name="scope"
    expression="( cflow(call(* ext.demo.Report.\*(..))) && execution(* ext.demo.QueryUtil.*(..)))"/>
```

Could anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only odd thing in your pointcut is the rogue '\' I see ahead of the * in the cflow pointcut component. I'd also suggest using execution() if you can rather than call() (there are typically lots of call sites to instrument but only one execution site).

```
cflow(execution(* ext.demo.Report.*(..))) && execution(* ext.demo.QueryUtil.*(..))
```

If it isn't behaving for you then break it down to work out which piece is at fault. Does `execution(* ext.demo.QueryUtil.*(..))` match everything you expect? Does `execution(* ext.demo.Report.*(..))` match everything you expect? (I'd use `-showWeaveInfo` to check)

Comment: Sorry, The "odd thing" was my fault during writing the question. Don't know why I wanted to escape *.. Thank You very much for solving my problem! It works perfectly fine.